# Value not saving after form is submitted

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a mysql table with two columns. One is ID and other is Heading. I have a textarea on which I run `UPDATE` code and whenever someone submits a form its being updated in the datebase column under heading. And that works fine but I want to show the last inputted submit inside my textarea. 
My code is showing the last inputted value but when I reset the page it all turns out blank and its not showing anymore. I looked out in datebase and the heading is still there so I don't know why its dissapearing from the front end.

My page:

```
<?php 

$title = 'Admin Panel - Edit';
include '../config.php';

$heading = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['heading']);

$sql = "UPDATE content SET heading='$heading' WHERE id = 1 ";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) == false){
     echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

$value=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT heading FROM content WHERE id = 1");
$currentText = mysqli_fetch_row($value);

?>

<form action="edit.php">
    <?php echo $currentText[0]; ?>
    <input type="text" name="heading" id="heading" value='<?php echo $currentText[0]; ?>' />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

So for example if I type Aleksa, after submit it will get url like `edit.php?heading=Aleksa&submit=Submit`. And then when I delete url just to `edit.php`, the value is missing.

You can test the page here: https://www.easybewussterschaffen.com/admin/edit.php

Comment: Because it's actively inserting the heading when you refresh the page. You should check to see if the request is `GET` or the request is `POST`, and only insert it if they're submitting the form.

Comment: Or check if `$_REQUEST['submit']` is set.

Comment: If you are allowing any user to update you also will be open to XSS injections.

Comment: Oh i'm not, this will be the admin panel where I will be editing content throughout my website, I will protect it with htaccess for now.

Comment: Famous last words...

Answer (score 0):

This is happening, because it's always trying to insert the heading when you refresh the page. You should check to see if the request is `GET` or the request is `POST`, and only insert it if they're submitting the form.

Update your form method, specify it to `POST`, and specifically check the method or check for the existance of `$_POST['submit']` as shown below:

```
<?php 

$title = 'Admin Panel - Edit';
include '../config.php';

// Use one of the 2 if statements:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { // Trying to insert a new heading
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Alternative

    $heading = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['heading']);

    $sql = "UPDATE content SET heading='$heading' WHERE id = 1 ";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) == false){
         echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}

$value=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT heading FROM content WHERE id = 1");
$currentText = mysqli_fetch_row($value);

?>

<form action="edit.php" method="POST">
    <?php echo $currentText[0]; ?>
    <input type="text" name="heading" id="heading" value='<?php echo $currentText[0]; ?>' />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Alternatively, if you still wish to make a GET request, you should check to make sure that the heading is set:

```
<?php 

$title = 'Admin Panel - Edit';
include '../config.php';

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

    $heading = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['heading']);

    $sql = "UPDATE content SET heading='$heading' WHERE id = 1 ";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) == false){
         echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}

$value=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT heading FROM content WHERE id = 1");
$currentText = mysqli_fetch_row($value);

?>

<form action="edit.php" method="GET">
    <?php echo $currentText[0]; ?>
    <input type="text" name="heading" id="heading" value='<?php echo $currentText[0]; ?>' />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @FreelancerHelp Do you understand why it happened though?

Comment: hey sorry it turns out its not working, both solutinons, after I reset the page to default url it doesnt save the value

Comment: First code the page shows its not working, and the second with GET when I reset to default URL it shows: sdssdsds, and I updated it with another text

Comment: Make sure you're updating the `<form>` method attribute.

Comment: Add some debug. Right before your `mysqli_query`, add an echo: `echo "Inserting new heading: $heading";`. Are you seeing that ONLY when you want it to insert a heading. Use `var_dump()` and `print_r()` for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this, is this good tho? Its working

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo '';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $row['heading'];
        }
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
?>
```